# confidence interval for mean based on small sample when CLT does not hold

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, skewness, small-sample, truncated-distributions

*I have looked at similar questions but could not find an satisfactory answer. Please forgive if I'm wrong.*

I have a **small sample** (n = 24) and use the sample **mean** as estimator of the true mean. I want to construct a **confidence interval** for the true mean.

The following is known about the distribution of the data:

- **truncated support** on [a, b] (in my case [0, 2/3])
- **right skewed**
- there are focal points (i.e. lot of obs take a particular value (e.g. zero or 0.14), but the distribution is not discrete, any values on the support can occur)
- **CLT does not hold** (although positive and finite variance). When I resample 10,000 times (n = 24 with replacement) the distribution of sampling means is in no way normal (Shapiro rejects with p < 0.0001)

What I did so far is construct a bootstrapped CI based on these 10,000 sampling means. As expected the CI is quite wide and asymmetric. In principle I'm fine with it, but I wonder...

**1. Is this a legitimate approach to the problem?**

**2. Are there better ways to construct CI under such conditions?**

I'm not a trained statistician and would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Note that the CLT is a theorem about what happens as $n\to\infty$.  It is the case that sample means for iid observations that are drawn from a non-normal population are never actually normal at *any* finite sample size, and a large enough simulated sample of such means will be almost certain to reject normality with a consistent goodness of fir test. This tells you little about whether the normal approximation to the distribution of the sample mean at some sample size is any good for the purposes of constructing a confidence interval at some nominal coverage $1-\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining and clarifying @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica! Can you also offer an answer to my two questions?

Comment: I commented because I think your questions ought to change; see the information I put in my comment. For example, what you have done does not demonstrate that the "CLT does not hold"; so (for example) the questions appear to be based on a misunderstanding of the CLT. Its not 100% clear to me how you would seek to change them in the light of my comments, so to begin with my answer would be to reiterate my comment above and then seek clarification